# SQL: return a list of the latest actions of users

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE useractions
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT,
    modified BIGINT, //this is the time of the action in milliseconds
    status INT,      // 1 = placed, 2 = processing ,3 = shipping or 4 = completed, 5 = failed
    action_id INT    // 1 = buy, 2 = sell, 3 = exchange, etc
);
```

Now, given an action_id, how do I create an SQL query that returns the list of the latest actions (of any `status` except 1) by each user of that given action_id? The table is large (50k - 100k rows) so I am trying to be efficient by not scanning and returning the entire table and later checking for the latest actions in Java.

My attempt so far was to retrieve the entire table, then in the ResultSet (Java) I collect the latest actions. But I feel like I maybe able to avoid that inefficient way.

Note that each agent can have many actions of the same action_id, and I only need to retrieve their latest actions: one action per user. The `modified` column indicates the time the action was created.

The query should work on both MySQL and Oracle databases.

**Note: I sincerely would like to not distract people with other questions, like why the type is BIGINT, or 100k is not large..., so here is a heads-up: because the table was created by my team, and I am not allowed to change it. And query is called on frequent basis, so the query needs to be efficient.**

Comment: 50 - 100k rows is not large. you just need to ensure you have the proper indices on the table and you should have no issue. can you post any attempts you have made? also if you could provide either a sqlfiddle or an example output with some data it would make it much easier to answer your question

Comment: why use a bigint when a timestamp will do the same with timezones and let you use the builtin functionality to manipulate it?

Comment: @Simo watch the tone. lets focus on any attempts you have made and on you adding some data so we can adequately understand what you want to achieve. sounds like you want the greatest-n-per-group which is actually a tag on StackOverflow

Comment: @Simo: careful with the tone.  Not that you're being rude at all, but you're starting to make this sound like a boss-employee relationship.  If you're looking for free labor, this is the wrong place.  Please post your attempts first.

Comment: Yeah. Agree; I unintentionally made  the tone sound rude; my apologies.

Comment: why the down votes? Did people get offended by the comments, but not the question itself? If so, I already apologized for the short and uninteional comments.

Comment: @Simo I didn't downvote.. but I did notice that all of the downvotes came almost immediately after your edit telling ppl to not get distracted in the bold text.. thats kinda preachy.. but i dono thats just my opinion

Comment: :) Thanks, John. I will edit it to make the tone nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without any data this is really difficult to answer. however here is a stab at it

```
SELECT t.user_id, max(t.modified) as modified, t.status
FROM table t
JOIN
(   SELECT user_id
    FROM table
    WHERE action_id <> 1 and status = whatever 
)t1 ON t1.user_id = t.user_id
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Comment: Yes, I think this, and what you suggested earlier in your comment about "greatest-n-per-group" is actually what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Simo sure thing. if you upload data I can test it and make sure this is what you want... i'm a little hesitant about some of it but in theory it should work

Comment: Thanks. That answer should be enough. I should be able to test it, and modify it if needed. I wish I heard of "greatest-n-per-group" before. Great thing to know :)

Comment: John, what's not good about this query, as compared to yours: ``select user_id, max(modified) as latest_modified, status
from action_table
where status <> 1
GROUP BY user_id;``

Comment: @Simo the problem with that is MAX() will return a date for a user whether or not it meets the WHERE condition. so you have to select out those rows and use the aggregate on an outer query

Comment: oh, good catch. I almost felt that something was wrong with that simple query, but could not figure out.